# Countrows in multiple column based on partial text value

Tags: filter, count, powerbi, dax

For a project I need to be able to count the number of rows in a file, based on a text value in one of eight defined columns.

I want to count a row when one of the "Linked Issues" columns contains a text value that starts with "THGRW-".

I tried using the COUNTROWS function combined with FILTER for only one column, which looks like this:

Episode without SM =
COUNTROWS(FILTER('Sheet1', 'Sheet1'[Linked Issues.1] >= "THGRW-000"))

For multiple columns I wanted to just sum (using the + operator) the countrows functions, but already this function for a single column does not give me a result.

I attached a screenshot of what the sheet looks like.[image: Sheet1]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this where you pipe predicates that form an `OR`. You will need to type out a lot, here is a snippet:

```
Count =
VAR _string = "THGRW-"
RETURN
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( 
        Tbl,
        LEFT( Tbl[Linked Issues.1], 6 ) = _string 
         || LEFT( Tbl[Linked Issues.2], 6 ) = _string 
         ...
         || LEFT( Tbl[Linked Issues.8], 6 ) = _string 
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, when I try this I get a (blank) result if I add the measure to a card visual. Count = 
VAR _string = "THRGW-"
RETURN
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( 
        'Sheet1',
        LEFT( 'Sheet1'[Linked Issues.1], 6 ) = _string 
        || LEFT( 'Sheet1'[Linked Issues.2], 6 ) = _string 
...
        || LEFT( 'Sheet1'[Linked Issues.7], 6 ) = _string 
        || LEFT( 'Sheet1'[Linked Issues.8], 6 ) = _string 
    )
)

Comment: You need to write the expressions for columns 3-7 based on this snippet.

Comment: I did, so for every column I changed the 'x' in 'Sheet1'[Linked Issues.x]. The code does not give any errors, but still returns a blank.

Comment: I see. The formula should work just fine. Check your external filters?

Comment: Found the issue, which is a typo: The string should've been 'THGRW-'. But still have another: It counts for the first column (which in my source file results in 50, which is correct. But if I check for column 2 to 8, the formula still returns a blank.

Comment: Aha! My bad. There is no reason the formula should return a blank for your other columns. It should count all rows where at least one of your defined columns start with this string. If the data is poorly cleaned you may get wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot makes me think you missed a step in PowerQuery. Instead of having "LinkedIssues1", "LinkedIssues2"... etc, you should have just (Key, LinkedIssue) as your table and then you just do the count from there.